# How to get id values from object inner class name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, calendar

I have one page create by javascript and I have these fields. How can I navigate and get the inner values just from a class object like this?

```html
<li class="tdays" id="23 8 2021">
  <div class="info">Quinta</div>
  <div class="date">23</div>
  <div class="ev" id="562">
    <div class="ev-desc">
      <p>undefined</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

I'd like go get the `div class="ev" id="562"`

My code at now is

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("tdays");
  $('.tdays').click(function() {
    // console.log(this.id);
    // console.log(this.value)
    console.log(this[0]);
  });
});
```

Comment: you need to get all children divs elements?

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('.tdays [id].ev').forEach(node => console.log(node.id))` ... see also [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, note that the `id` attribute on the `.tdays` element is invalid - `id` cannot contain spaces.

To do what you require you can use jQuery's DOM traversal methods to find the `.ev` related to the clicked `.tdays` element and read its `id`. In this case you can use `children()` or `find()`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tdays').on('click', function() {
    let evId = $(this).children('.ev').prop('id');
    console.log(evId);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="tdays" id="23 8 2021">
    <div class="info">Quinta</div>
    <div class="date">23</div>
    <div class="ev" id="562">
      <div class="ev-desc">
        <p>undefined</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="tdays" id="02 9 2021">
    <div class="info">Quinta</div>
    <div class="date">02</div>
    <div class="ev" id="121">
      <div class="ev-desc">
        <p>undefined</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case the OP considers to give the DOM Api a try and there especially [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) ...

```js
function handleTDaysClick(evt) {
  const elmTDays = evt.currentTarget;
  const evNode = elmTDays.querySelector('[id].ev');

  console.log(evNode.id);
}
document
  .querySelectorAll('.tdays')
  .forEach(node =>
    node.addEventListener('click', handleTDaysClick)
  );
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%!important;
  top: 0;
  left: auto!important;
  width: 50%!important;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="tdays" id="23-8-2021">
    <div class="info">Quinta</div>
    <div class="date">23</div>
    <div class="ev" id="562">
      <div class="ev-desc">
        <p>undefined</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="tdays" id="02-9-2021">
    <div class="info">Quinta</div>
    <div class="date">02</div>
    <div class="ev" id="121">
      <div class="ev-desc">
        <p>undefined</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @PedroHenrique ... Saying thanks is nice. At SO an OP is encouraged to also credit the most helpful answer by clicking the "accept" link/button related to that answer.